# Why does $(6-2i) \cos{(\omega t+ \pi/3)} = (6-2i) \sin{(\pi/6 - \omega t)}$?

Tags: trigonometry

This question is pretty short and is essentially summed up in the title.  I am wondering why the multiplication of:
$$(6-2i)\cos{(\omega t + \pi/3)}= (6-2i) \sin{(\pi/6 - \omega t)}$$

My understanding was that you foiled when multiplying complex numbers which would give a very different result than the above answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This has nothing to do with complex numbers. Try proving that the $\cos$ term is equal to the $\sin$ term using a certain trig identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\cos{(\pi/2-x)} = \sin{x}, $$
set $x=\omega t + \pi/3$.

Answer (score 0):

How $\cos(x)=\sin(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-x)$. If $x=wt+\dfrac{\pi}{3}$ then

$\cos(wt+\dfrac{\pi}{3})=\sin(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-wt-\dfrac{\pi}{3})=\sin(\dfrac{\pi}{6}-wt)$